# Equivalent JPA Query for ANY operator in psql

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have an Entity which looks like this. I have removed some of the fields for simplicatation purpose :

```
@Entity    
public class ObjectMeta implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "inc_id", columnDefinition = "SERIAL")
private Integer id;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;
    @Column(name = "status", columnDefinition = "verification_status DEFAULT 'PENDING' NOT NULL")
private String status;

@Column(name = "categories", columnDefinition = "character varying (10)[]")
@Type(type = "stringUserType")
private List<String> categories;
@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "modified_on", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date modifiedOn;
@Column(name = "modified_by", columnDefinition = "character varying(100)")
private String modifiedBy;
}
```

Now I have an API which queries this entity based on the fields name, modified_by, modified_on. Also, there are other fields on which there are predicates similar to the one added for the name in the below code. This is a simplified version of my current function :

```
@Transactional
public List<AdomainMeta> getObjects(final String like, final String category) {
    final EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    final CriteriaQuery<ObjectMeta> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(ObjectMeta.class);

    final Root<ObjectMeta> metaRoot = criteriaQuery.from(ObjectMeta.class);
    final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(metaRoot.get("name")),like.toLowerCase()));

    criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));

    final TypedQuery<ObjectMeta> typedQuery = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

The above function is equivalent to the psql query below :

```
select * from object_meta where name like '%like%';
```

I just want to add a predicate to make this function equivalent to the below psql query:

```
select * from object_meta where name like '%like%' and 'category' = ANY(categories);
```

I have tried googling the equivalent of psql ANY operator in JPA but haven't found anything substantial. Any help is appreciated. Also is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#isMember-E-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-

Comment: @JBNizet thanks. Yeah I am trying that but the isMember expects a PluralAttributePath collectionExpression but mine is SingularAttributePath and is thus throwing IllegalArgumentException.  How can I fix that?

Comment: That's because your mapping is incorrect. You can't possibly store a whole list of strings into a column. Your list of categories must be annotated with ElementCollection.

Comment: I have a custom type StringArrayUserType(@Type(type = "stringUserType")) which implemts UserType .  My categories is of type StringArrayUserType. PSQL db supports varchar array .

Comment: Then you probably need a custom function (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...-) or SQL

Comment: annotating with ElementCollection causes org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table ObjectMeta_categories

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193008/discussion-between-sourav-prem-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 0):

Try `in`.

```
predicates.add(cb.in(cb.parameter(String.class, "cat")));
... // non-empty collection. not array
typedQuery.setParameter("cat", categoryCollection);
```

In PostgreSQL the expression `a IN (b,c,e)` is internally converted to `a = ANY(ARRAY[b,c,e])`, and `a NOT IN (b,c,e)` becomes `a <> ALL (ARRAY[b,c,e])`.

However it seems like you might be looking for the wrong operator. Do you want it to contain any of the ones in the parameter or all of them? Because `anyarray = ANY(anyarray)` will not work.